# How to hang wood letters

Tags: woodworking, routers

I have cut out a word made of 1/2" poplar and would like to hang it in the wall. I originally thought of using my (non plunge) router with a keyhole bit to cut two keyholes, but I'm afraid that the wood would be too thin. Is there any way to do this nice other than picture hangers?

Edit:
I don't want to glue it to the wall because that would cause too much damage to the wall. My current hair brain idea is to drill a hole with a forstner bit and then maybe use a t router bit to cut a slot for the keyhole

Comment: Is this multiple letters that have to be arranged or one piece of wood?

Comment: The letters are all cut out in cursive and form one single piece of wood as they are all connected.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is one piece of wood  screw two of these eyes to the back in strategic locations. Hang it on picture frame hooks

[image]

Comment: Yah, I was trying to think of a way that is more "custom" looking, but this is my fallback plan

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two alternatives that would be workable.

1. Glue the wooden letters directly to the wall. Construction adhesive would be one type of glue that would work but since the letters are probably rather light weight you may also be able to make gel type super glue work as well. This approach will likely work best on a drywall type wall material rather than a fancy wood covered wall because at some future time when you want the letters gone it will be easier to repair the surface of the wall.
2. Glue the letters to an appropriately sized thin piece of clear acrylic plastic or Lexan. Then simply hang the plastic panel with some simple hangers or screws.

Answer (score 0):

I would use mounting tape. It should work with letters up to about 12", maybe larger. *Scotch outdoor mounting tape* is the one that I use, even indoors when I need high strength. You will likely damage the wall when it is removed, but probably less than if they were glued.